# Adjusting a javascript line

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get **Code 2** to work

This line in that code needs to be adjusted in it, but I don't know how I would fix it.

```
  const otherVideos = (video) => video !== player.getVideoUrl() !== temp;
```

After a second video is clicked, the one before it pauses.

**This Works:** Code 1

https://jsfiddle.net/d72Lp43v/418/

```
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      const temp = event.target.getVideoUrl();
      const otherVideos = (player) => player.getVideoUrl() !== temp;
      const pauseVideo = (player) => player.pauseVideo();
      players.filter(otherVideos).forEach(pauseVideo);
    }
    const player = event.target;
    const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
    if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
    }
  }
```

And this code doesn’t, how come?

**Code 2**

https://jsfiddle.net/d72Lp43v/421/

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      const temp = event.target.getVideoUrl();
      const otherVideos = (video) => video !== player.getVideoUrl() !== temp;
      const pauseVideo = (video) => video.pauseVideo();
      players.filter(otherVideos).forEach(pauseVideo);
    }

    const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
    if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
    }
  }
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't tell us what you want to express. Maybe you want `video !== player.getVideoUrl()  && video !== temp`

Comment: After a second video is clicked, the one before it pauses. That's how it's working in the 1st code.

Comment: That didn't work, I just tried it.

Comment: *"And this code doesn’t, how come?"* `a === b === c` is processing the code left to right, i.e. `(a === b) === c`. `a === b` is either `false` or `true`, so you are really doing `false === c` or `true === c`.

Comment: You have to explain to use what `video !== player.getVideoUrl() !== temp;` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I'm trying to get Code 1, to work the same as Code 2. After a second video is clicked, the one before it pauses.

Comment: OK, why are you adding `video !==`?

Comment: I was trying to simplify the code.

Comment: the second code is semantically wrong, your `otherVideos` function expects a video url but parameter name indicates that it's a video object, you're filtering the list of players which you seem to interchange with video objects

Comment: How would I fix it? How would I fix that line?

Comment: I can't screw something if I don't know what it will hold, in short could you show us some real code ?

Comment: This is Code 1 Working https://jsfiddle.net/d72Lp43v/418/ / This is Code 2 Not working https://jsfiddle.net/d72Lp43v/421/ The one I'm trying to fix.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside `otherVideos` function(probably needs curly braces) can you compare the value of `player` in Code 1 vs `video` in Code 2

Comment: Code 1: const otherVideos = (player) => player.getVideoUrl() !== temp; / Code 2: const otherVideos = (video) => video !== player.getVideoUrl() !== temp;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change that line to:

```
  const otherVideos = video => video.getVideoUrl() != player.getVideoUrl()
```

This will do what you want. It just makes sure that the `filter` does not include the current video by comparing the `urls` strings.

You also this way do not need `temp` variable.

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akrion/o3yxbrk0/)

Comment: "filter does not include the current video by comparing the urls" What do you mean by that, can you give an example?

Comment: `video.getVideoUrl() != player.getVideoUrl()` those are 2 `url` strings which you compare and in your `otherVideos` the point of comparison is to make sure that the you filter out the currently playing video.

Comment: How would I be able to make this line shorter?
const otherVideos = (video) => video.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl(); https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/6/

Comment: Not sure I follow. Why shorter? It seems as short as it could be plus minus few chars. We already got rid of the `temp` etc. Also this would be out of context to this question. If you have something else specific in mind post a different question otherwise the comments and the context for this question get lots etc.

Comment: 80 character limit. jslint.

Comment: Ok make the variable names shorter :) `const other = v => v.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl();` or something among those lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
players.filter(otherVideos)
```

I think filter always return full list.

Each player is not url, so `video !== player.getVideoUrl()` is `true`. And `true` is not url. `true !== temp` is also true.

I don't know what you want to improve code 1. 
However I think you want to write is following:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      const temp = event.target.getVideoUrl();
      // only change this line:
      const otherVideos = (video) => video.getVideoUrl() !== player.getVideoUrl() && video.getVideoUrl() !== temp;
      const pauseVideo = (video) => video.pauseVideo();
      players.filter(otherVideos).forEach(pauseVideo);
    }

    const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
    if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
    }
}
```